# JS: Adding up values inside an object

Tags: javascript, jquery

The expire, target, and quoted variables will always be numeric. I'm wanting to tally up each one.

How would I get the current `total['expire']` inside the `total = {}` object? I think I may be going about this the wrong way.

```
data = [];
$('tr.count').each(function(i) {

    var self = $(this),
        expire = self.find('td:nth-of-type(2) input').val(),
        target = self.find('td:nth-of-type(3) input').val(),
        quoted = self.find('td:nth-of-type(4) input').val();

        data[i] = {
            expire : expire,
            target : target,
            quoted : quoted,
        };

        total = {
            expire : expire, // in php I would do 'expire' += $expire;
            target : target,
            quoted : quoted,
        };

});
```

Comment: UM, your code makes no sense, you declare it as an array outside and override it with an object inside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define the total outside and increment it inside.

```
data = [];
total = {
    expire : 0,
    target: 0,
    quoted: 0
};
$('tr.count').each(function(i) {

    var self = $(this),
        expire = self.find('td:nth-of-type(2) input').val(),
        target = self.find('td:nth-of-type(3) input').val(),
        quoted = self.find('td:nth-of-type(4) input').val();

        data[i] = {
            expire : expire,
            target : target,
            quoted : quoted,
        };

        total.expire += expire;
        total.target += target;
        total.quoted += quoted;

});
```

Comment: Would need a parseInt() to prevent the numbers forming a string. Thanks tho. :)